# Solving L infinity norm using Linear programming in python

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

The objective function of the problem is to minimize

```
maxi∈[1,...,N]|yi−(w⊤xi+b)|
```

How to proceed in setting the objective function ? Can you please explain it in pulp or Lingo or Gurobi ?

Comment: This is essentially a max of a max. This would require some tricks with binary variables (or SOS1 variables). Gurobi has both abs() and max() functions in its API, so that would make things easier.

Comment: If I convert the objective function to minimize the residual sum. Given the constraints, that deals with residual sum >= e and  - residual sum >= e and error >= e so that it is reduced to minimization problem, can you please let me know how this can be framed in pulp or gurobi.. Because I couldnt figure out how we can give the constraints like this

Comment: That approach will not work due to non-convexity of the problem (it would work if the objective is to minimize). As said before, you can use abs() and Max() functions in Gurobi. That makes the problem almost trivial.